# How to concatenate a command by sub string in make file?

Tags: makefile

I want to use Makefile to integrate my operation, not only compile.
Here is my Makefile

```
SHELL:=/bin/bash
.ONESHELL:

all:
    cmd="du"
    cmd+=" -a"
    cmd+=" -h"
    echo ${cmd}
    ${cmd}
```

However, the output is

```
cmd="du"
cmd+=" -a"
cmd+=" -h"
echo
```

It seems that the `cmd` variable is not work.
How can I use the variable concatenate in Makefile to make them compose an long command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $ sign needs to be escaped to avoid `make` interpreting it :

```
all:
    cmd="du"
    cmd+=" -a"
    cmd+=" -h"
    echo $${cmd}
    $${cmd}
```